# How to randomly sample a subset of a song on command line

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

From the command line, I'd like to play a audio clip, or random subset of a song, eg, seconds 5 - 10. This does not seem to be a feature of `paplay` or `mpg123`, the two programs I've been using.

`ffmpeg` allos me to trim a file (eg, `ffmpeg -i file.mkv -ss 20 -to 40 -c copy file-2.mkv`), but I'd like to avoid creating a new file. Piping the above does not seem to work, though I may be doing it wrong.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach works fine for me. Use force format option `-f` and select wave, write to stdout then pipe to e.g. `aplay` like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input -ss 20 -to 40 -f wav - | aplay
```

Comment: Or if you have ffplay: `ffplay -ss 20 -t 20 input`

Comment: Works. Thanks. Is there a way to get `ffplay` or `aplay` to exit when the clip finishes? Right now it continues playing. Would prefer not to have to kill the process.

Comment: `ffplay -ss 20 -t 20 input -autoexit`